# How to get 'range' of items in descending order?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var myArray = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
```

I use `slice` to get range between: 2 to 4: `myArray.slice(2, 4);`. works great.

But how to get from 4 to 2? slice doesn't do it. is there a js function does that?

Comment: you could sort the sliced array in the descending order.

Comment: `myArray.slice(2,4).reverse()`

Comment: @Abhilash you are assuming that `myArray` is already sorted. If it is, then your comment will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.reverse`:

```js
var myArray = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
myArray = myArray.slice(2,4).reverse();
console.log(myArray);
```

You can also `sort` if you want to make sure of the order by the value of `x`:

```js
var myArray = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
myArray = myArray.slice(2,4).sort((a,b)=>b.x-a.x);
console.log(myArray);
```